# To calculate by the index of the element its number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I specify a formula to calculate by the index of the element its number? 
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of $(s,1)$ is ${s+1\choose 2}=\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$ (do you see why?).

Given index $n$, we first try to find the maximal $s$ with $\frac{s(s+1)}{2}<n$, or  equivalently: with $s^2+s<2n$. As both sides are integers, this is equivalent to $(s+\frac12)^2=s^2+s+\frac14<2n$. Hence we let $s=\lfloor\sqrt{2n}-\frac12\rfloor$.
Now we know that the pair $(i,j)$ with index $n$ is in the diagonal following that of $(s,1)$, which tells us that $i+j=s+2$. Also, we know that the index of $(s,1)$ is $\frac{2(s+1)} 2$ so that $(i,j)$ is the $(n-\frac{2(s+1)} 2)$th element of that diagonal. In other words: $i=n-\frac{2(s+1)} 2$, $j=s+2-i=s+2+\frac{2(s+1)} 2-n$.

Example: $n=8$ leads to $s=\lfloor \sqrt{16}-\frac12\rfloor=3$, $i=8-\frac{3\cdot 4}{2}=2$, $j=3+2-2=3$, so index $8$ is at $(2,3)$.

Comment: I could have *never* understood why this drawing represents this formula.